# C++, popup menu scroll bar

Tags: c++, winapi

how can i add a vertical scroll bar on this popup menu? have set popup size but does not appear.

```
int FTPWindow::OnProfileChange() {
    if (!m_vProfiles)
        return -1;

    ::DestroyMenu(m_popupProfile);
    m_popupProfile = ::CreatePopupMenu();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_vProfiles->size(); i++) {
        ::AppendMenu(m_popupProfile, MF_STRING, IDM_POPUP_PROFILE_FIRST + i, m_vProfiles->at(i)->GetName());
    }
    MENUINFO mi = { sizeof(MENUINFO) };
    mi.fMask = MIM_MAXHEIGHT;
    mi.cyMax = 400;
    SetMenuInfo(m_popupProfile, &mi);
    POINT point = {100,100};
    HWND window;
    ClientToScreen(window, &point);
    TrackPopupMenu(m_popupProfile, TPM_RETURNCMD, 100, 100,0,window,NULL);
    m_toolbar.SetMenu(IDB_BUTTON_TOOLBAR_CONNECT, m_popupProfile);

    SetToolbarState();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware that you can add a scrollbar to a popup menu.

Comment: Not to my knowledge either. I think what you see in some programs are custom controls. Just a quick idea: create a combobox, possibly a hidden one and send it `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` to show the list box programmatically, which could serve as your "menu".

Comment: Vertical scrollbars are added to standard popup menus only, when they do not fit the screen. This is done by the system. The menu class does not expose this functionality.